# Tensor product of flat real line bundles and triviality.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $L$ be a real line bundle over a manifold $M$. Equivalence classes of real line bundles over $M$ are in correspondence with elements of $H^{1}(M,\mathbb{Z}_{2})$ through the first Stiefel-Whitney class isomorphism $w_{1}\colon \mathrm{Vec}_{1}(M)\to H^{1}(M,\mathbb{Z}_{2})$. Then, $L^2 = L\otimes L$ is always trivial, since

$w_{1}(L^2) = w_{1}(L) + w_{1}(L) = [0]$

Suppose that $L$ is a flat line bundle with positive constant transition functions $\lambda_{ab}\colon U_{a}\cap U_{b}\to \mathbb{R}$. Then we can formally take the square root $L^{1/2}$ of $L$ defined as the line bundle constructed from $\left\{ M, U_{a}, \lambda^{1/2}_{ab},\mathbb{R}\right\}$. Then

$L\simeq L^{1/2}\otimes L^{1/2} = \left( L^{1/2}\right)^{2}$

and then $L$ must be trivial, since it is the square of a line bundle. We conclude that a flat line bundle with positive transition functions is always trivial. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those positive transition functions mean precisely that the bundle is orientable (reduction of the structure group to $SO(n)$. But a line bundle is trivial iff orientable, since an orientation corresponds to a continous choice of a basis and this gives you a nowhere vanishing section, hence a trivialization.

To sum up:

$$ L \text{ trivial} \Leftrightarrow L \text{ has a nowhere zero section} \Leftrightarrow L \text{ orientable} \Leftrightarrow w_1(L)=0$$

Comment: Either you should write "$L$ has a nowhere vanishing section" or you should make clear that you are talking about  a section of the associated $GL(n)$ bundle. Every vector bundle has a section.