# Cocycle condition for line bundles.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $L\to M$ a flat line bunle. Then we can find a covering $U_{a}$ with local transition functions $\lambda \colon U_{a}\cap U_{b}\to\mathbb{R}$. Apparently, the cocycle condition

$\lambda_{ab}\lambda_{bc}\lambda_{ca} = 1$

implies that $\lambda_{ab} = \frac{\Delta_{a}}{\Delta_{b}}$, where $\Delta_{a}\colon U_{a}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a non-vanishing real function, and analogously for $\Delta_{b}$. Where can I find such proof?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is actually equivalent to the fact that $L$ is the trivial bundle. Indeed, if you can construct functions $\Delta_a:U_a\to \mathbb{R}^*$ with the property that $\frac{\Delta_a}{\Delta_b}=\lambda_{ab}$, then they glue together to give a global never vanishing section of $L$. Since $L$ has rank one, it must be trivial.

On the other hand, not every real flat line bundle is trivial; the easiest example is the Mobius band: you can find a covering of $S^1$ with three open arcs on which the transitions are just $1$ and $-1$; the problem here is that they are not all positive: have a look at [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1148234/22002), where they show that the bundle will be trivial if transition functions are all positive. In this case you can take a global section $f$ and define $\Delta_a =f|_{U_a}$ to get the local functions you want.